# How to override gcc of the linux host computer with a gcc docker container

Tags: linux, docker, gcc, g++

I am considering to use gcc from [official docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/gcc) for two reasons:

- can't wait years for my linux distribution to deliver their offical packages so that I can use features of the recent gcc version. Compiling gcc myself from source requires too much effort
- want to change gcc versions easily to see the differences

I managed to substitue the gcc command temporarily with the following alias:

```
alias gcc="docker run --user $(id -u):$(id -g) --rm -t -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp gcc:8.2 gcc"
```

Then I can use `gcc hello.c`at the console of the host and I get hello.c compiled by gcc version 8.2 from the docker image instead of version 7.3 of the host.

This works also fine, if the source file is in a subdirectory. E.g. `gcc foo/hello.c`

The problem is what happens if the source file is in a higher directory. E.g.

```
cd foo && gcc ../hello.c
```

I get the error message:

> gcc: error: ../hello.cpp: No such file or directory

I think this is because the current directory of the host is mapped to the working directory = `/usr/src/myapp` of the container and `..` goes outside of that working directory of the container. See above the `-v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp` part of the alias.

Is there a way to overcome this difficulty?

Comment: Since Docker goes out of its way to isolate a lot of the container contents from the host system (a container has its own filesystem and user names, for example) it’s not a great match for what you’re trying to do.  Installing gcc from source with a custom `--prefix` is probably hairy but will give a much better outcome; or using Vagrant to connect up a VM with the tools you need with a newer base distribution might be better.  IME there are not significant changes between gcc versions where this really matters, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would have to mount root.

```
alias gcc='docker run --user $(id -u):$(id -g) --rm -t -v /:/mnt -w /mnt/"$PWD" gcc:8.2 gcc'
```

Note that this will still not work with absolute paths.

Comment: I would **STRONGLY** recommend `-v /:/mnt:ro` to prevent modifications from inside container to host file system root

Comment: @grapes: The answer works (also with the read only option) as I desired. But I am puzzled why the expected `a.out` file can be created by the container although I use the ro option?